# Python Screen Recorder nothing happens

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to use ready made code to capture the game. But when I run it, nothing happens, but there are no errors, what could be the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

def screen_record(): 
    last_time = time.time()
    while(True):
        # 800x600 windowed mode for GTA 5, at the top left position of your main screen.
        # 40 px accounts for title bar. 
        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()
        cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

screen_record()
```

Comment: please always give your code in code block to check

Comment: If it doesn't print how long the loop took, it isn't running at all.